# Iterate over elements string in one line

Tags: c++, string

I have two strings, i.e: `APPLE` and `APPLEA`. I want to iterate over `APPLE` and check if its characters belong to `APPLEA`. I have done this:

```
int counter=0;
for (j=0;j<dictionary[i].size();j++)
{
    if (word_to_match.find(dictionary[i][j]) != std::string::npos)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Where dictionary is just a std::vector that has `APPLE` and other words.
Is it possible to avoid the for loop by using std::transform or another tool?

----------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------

I have this, I dont know if it could be even cleaner

```
    std::for_each(dictionary[i].begin(),dictionary[i].end(),[&word_to_match,&counter](char const &c){
        if (word_to_match.find(c) != std::string::npos)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide some additional input, and output cases? I'm not clear what the algorithm is doing.

Comment: Is your end result to have the number of matched characters?

Answer (score 0):

How about [std::count_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
int count = std::count_if(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), [&](const std::string& s){
        return word_to_match.find(s) != std::string::npos;
    });
```

assuming `dictionary` is a container for `std::string`, eg. `std::vector<std::string>`. You can modify it accordingly to match your case.

Comment: As it seems OP wants then to check `count` with size, `std::all_of` seems appropriate.